# Цвет кода в файле tsx и ts белый

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image: Вот в файле tsx весь текст белый]

[image: А вот в файле js всё нормально, текст разными цветами]

Буду благодарен, если поможете решить проблему!!!

Comment: Ищите в настройках `"files.associations"` или мешающие расширения

Comment: Помогло, спасибо